# UIPickerView with two rows

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview

I am trying to make a simple converter for some unit stuff, and i can't seem to manage getting the data out of both columns and making them into a variable i can calculate with. I also get some errors, which i would really appreciate if anyone would look into. The errors are at the #pragma mark - PickerView Delegate, where i think about 90% of my code is wrong.

Here is the full .h file.   (Hoping i did this the right way this time) 
And here is the full project if anyone has got the time to look into it. http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?ss706o783ioa59u

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize _convertFrom, _convertTo, _convertRates;
@synthesize dollarText, picker, resultLabel;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
_convertFrom = @[@"Australia (AUD)", @"China (CNY)",
@"France (EUR)", @"Great Britain (GBP)", @"Japan (JPY)"];

_convertRates = @[ @0.9922f, @6.5938f, @0.7270f,
@0.6206f, @81.57f];

_convertTo = @[@"Australia (AUD)", @"China (CNY)",
@"France (EUR)", @"Great Britain (GBP)", @"Japan (JPY)"];

_convertRates = @[ @0.9922f, @6.5938f, @0.7270f,
@0.6206f, @81.57f];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
//dont forget to put something in here later
}

- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender {
[sender resignFirstResponder];

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView DataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:      (NSInteger)component
{
if (component == 0)  {
    return [_convertFrom count];
}
return [_convertTo count];
}


- (NSString *) pickerView: (UIPickerView *)pickerView
          titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
         forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if (component == 0) {
    return [_convertFrom objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    }
return [_convertTo objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];
    }




#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView Delegate
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
  inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    float from = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]     floatValue]];
    float to = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1] floatValue]];
float input = [dollarText.text floatValue];

// This stuff is from some guide.
//float rate = [_convertRates[row] floatValue];
//float dollars = [dollarText.text floatValue];
//float result = dollars * rate;

NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                          @"%.2f @% = %.2f %@", input, [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] floatValue]], result, [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] floatValue]]];
resultLabel.text = resultString;
}


#pragma mark - Flipside View

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    }
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What are the errors? Don't make us guess. :) Are they compiler errors or runtime errors? Clearly indicate the exact error and which line it is associated with.

Comment: I am sorry, compiler error. pretty much every live beyond pragma pickerview delegate. most of them are "missing ";"", compiling errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked at your code, but still have some doubts about your calculation, but your braces was wrong and please implement it like this only:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    float from = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue];
    float to = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]] floatValue];
    float input = [dollarText.text floatValue];

    // This stuff is from some guide.
    float rate = from;
    float dollars = input;
    float result = dollars * rate;

    NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                              @"result = %f = %f * %f", result, dollars, rate];
    resultLabel.text = resultString;
}
```

-(IBAction)clear
{

}

Comment: It's not about the calcluation, its about to get stuff working and retrieving numbers from the wheely.

Comment: Thanks, that helped alot. I still get "Expected ';'" at
    
--
    float from = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] floatValue]];

Comment: Buddy you have used wrong braces: Use it like above mentioned:
float from = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue];

Comment: Thanks alot. I can't upvote because my account is new, but I give you a hypothetical high-five.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines:

```
float from = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]     floatValue]];
float to = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1] floatValue]];
```

should be:

```
float from = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue];
float to = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]] floatValue];
```

You have bracket in the wrong spot. And it looks like the 'resultString' line has the same problem, multiple times.

Comment: Thanks alot. I still get "Expected ';'" when compiling that line tho. Any tips?